# websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 403 when running in python anywhere

Tags: websocket, pythonanywhere

When trying to run my .py script it's showing the error

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketProxyException: failed CONNECT via proxy status: 403
```

I am using a module tvdatafeed which uses websocket. Please help to solve the issue. So that I can test my script on cloud

Answer (score 0):

Free accounts cannot connect out to websocket endpoints.